# How Can I add Extra Login Field to Django App and use session to identify User

Tags: python, django

I am working a Django Real Estate Management website where I want users to choice their Categories (Landlord, Agent, Prospect) upon registration and login. For the Registration I did it but for the User login I am unable to add extra user login field for successful login.
Django Form Code:

```
USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
('landlord', 'Landlord'),
('agent', 'Agent'),
('prospect', 'Prospect'),
)
class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
user_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control left-label'}))
```

Django Login View code:

```
class MyLoginView(LoginView):
template_name = 'account/login.html'
authentication_form = UserLoginForm

def get_form(self, form_class=None):
    form = super().get_form(form_class)
    form.fields['user_type'] = forms.ChoiceField(
        label='User Type',
        choices=[('landlord', 'Landlord'), ('agent', 'Agent'), ('prospect', 'Prospect')],
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control left-label'})
    )
    return form

def form_valid(self, form):
    user = form.get_user()
    user_type = form.cleaned_data['user_type']
    
    # Check if the selected user type matches the user's actual user type
    if user_type == 'landlord' and not user.profile.landlord:
        messages.error(self.request, 'Invalid user type for this user.')
        return self.form_invalid(form)
    elif user_type == 'agent' and not hasattr(user, 'agent'):
        messages.error(self.request, 'Invalid user type for this user.')
        return self.form_invalid(form)
    elif user_type == 'prospect' and not hasattr(user, 'prospect'):
        messages.error(self.request, 'Invalid user type for this user.')
        return self.form_invalid(form)
    
    login(self.request, user)
    self.request.session['user_type'] = user_type
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Anytime I try loading the login page this is the error: ****init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'** someone should help with solution.

Comment: Share the full traceback...

Comment: Your form also does not seem to have a `get_user` method...

Comment: Can you rewrite the code to fix the bug

Comment: well people can help you a lot easier... if you help with requests for clarifications...

Answer (score 2):

You should let the form inherit from `AuthenticationForm`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('landlord', 'Landlord'),
    ('agent', 'Agent'),
    ('prospect', 'Prospect'),
)


class UserLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    user_type = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES,
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control left-label'}),
    )
```

patching the field in the view is *not* necessary nor useful.

Comment: So should the new view code look like

Answer (score 0):

Using the form as shown below:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
('landlord', 'Landlord'),
('agent', 'Agent'),
('prospect', 'Prospect'),
)


class UserLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
user_type = forms.ChoiceField(
    choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES,
    widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control left-label'}),
)
```

The modified version of my view code where I added the login function from django.contrib.auth to authenticate the user. After successful authentication, the user type (user_type) is stored in the session using self.request.session['user_type']. This ensures that the user is properly authenticated and their user type is stored in the session for further use in the application. I changed the authentication_form attribute to form_class since form_class is the appropriate attribute to specify the form class to use. In the form_valid method,

```
from django.contrib.auth import login

class MyLoginView(LoginView):
template_name = 'account/login.html'
form_class = UserLoginForm

def form_valid(self, form):
    user = form.get_user()
    user_type = form.cleaned_data['user_type']

    # Check if the selected user type matches the user's actual user type
    if user_type == 'landlord' and not hasattr(user, 'landlord'):
        form.add_error('user_type', 'Invalid user type for this user.')
        return self.form_invalid(form)
    elif user_type == 'agent' and not hasattr(user, 'agent'):
        form.add_error('user_type', 'Invalid user type for this user.')
        return self.form_invalid(form)
    elif user_type == 'prospect' and not hasattr(user, 'prospect_profile'):
        form.add_error('user_type', 'Invalid user type for this user.')
        return self.form_invalid(form)

    # Authenticate the user
    login(self.request, user)

    # Set user type in the session
    self.request.session['user_type'] = user_type

    return super().form_valid(form)
```

On the HTML Template

```
{% if messages %}
              <ul class="messages">
                 {% for message in messages %}
                    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
                 {% endfor %}
              </ul>
              {% endif %}
<form method="post" action="{% url 'account-login' %}">
                 {% csrf_token %}
                 {{ form | crispy }}
                 <p>
                   <button type="submit">Login</button>
                 </p>
              </form>
```